# Inconsistent tag badge text

Tags: discussion, tag-badges

The requirements text seems to carry different meanings in different places for the tag badges. I shall use the gold tag badges as an example

**Gold badges page**
The text explaining the requirements for the tag badges appears to be inconsistent. For example here on the [gold badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=gold) the requirement for the gold tag badge is:

> You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki
>   answers to achieve this badge.

A score of 1000 could imply 100 upvotes (at a score of 10 a piece, possibly with adjustment for downvotes).

**Specific badge page**
On the other hand the  [badge itself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) says:

> Earned 1000 upvotes for at least 200 answers in the ??? tag

I realise that score is a somewhat ambiguous term but I expect others will share my score=reputation assumption. It is at the very least ambiguous at present.

Even if we assume score=votes (which having looked carefully is clearly the case) then they remain subtly different as the first includes downvotes whereas the second interpretation doesn't.

Comment: I realise bug may be a little bit of an extreme tag to give this, but of the 4 required tags it seemed the closest fit

Comment: I would say [meta-tag:discussion] would be a better fit...

Comment: @m0sa I suppose it is a discussion as to whether this is in fact wrong or if my interpretation is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [FAQ on badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) states clearly:

> The term score means the total number of upvotes minus the total number of downvotes.

So there's no problem with the gold badge page, but the page that says "1000 upvotes" should be fixed. I believe someone with 1000 upvotes precisely, and non zero downvotes, or 1001 upvotes and 1 or more downvotes (etc) would **not** get the badge.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't want to come down heavily on one text vs the other (although possibly the definition of score should be on the badges page itself), just that the two definitions couldn't both simultaneously be true

Comment: This fix now appears to have been implemented