# Do some types of deleted posts not show up in the Recently Deleted section in the "deleted posts" 10k tool?

Tags: support, 10k-tools, deleted-posts, recently-deleted

On a site where I have 10,000 reputation the Recently Deleted section of the [Tools](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tools) page shows me only one post deleted 15 hours ago:

[image: Screenshot of recently deleted section]

However, I know that [a post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/110737/if-one-davened-shacharis-without-tefillin-b-mezid-has-he-fulfilled-his-onligati) was just deleted within the last half hour:

[image: Screenshot of deleted post with deletion timestamp]

Is there some reason why this recently deleted post doesn't show up in the Recently Deleted section? Are there certain types of deletions that aren't recorded there?

A relevant factor may be that the poster's account was removed:

[image: Screenshot showing removed account]

Would that cause the post to not show up in the Recently Deleted section?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274100/in-10k-tools-show-posts-that-are-automatically-deleted-when-a-users-account-is

Comment: @Catija just curious - Yaakov's answer refers to this change? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192878/295232

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes. ... I'm pretty sure this is intentional... for example, if a mod nukes a spammer, we don't want to clutter this page up with those posts. Similarly if someone posts a bad question, deletes their profile after a few downvotes and the question is deleted by the system when they delete the profile... again, what is the need to show those questions to the 10k users? I'm trying to see what the logic is to make sure that it's behaving as designed.

Comment: @Catija This [came up on ELL after a self delete of an account](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5511/9161). Would it be possible to at least put the positively scored answers of the low scored question in recently deleted so that the community has a chance to see if anything needs “rescued”?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this seems related to the deletion of the account. I've just checked the list of recently deleted posts on Ask Different; one of them was a spam post posted 2 hours ago. I proceeded to destroy the account; when I checked the Recently Deleted section again, the post was gone there. A later test revealed that just deleting the account (instead of destroying it) also removes the post from the Recently Deleted section.

Comment: Another case is when the author deletes the post himself.