# What does Stack Overflow do about posts that have been deleted years ago or months ago?

Tags: discussion

I want to know if my question was deleted 4 months ago.  I don't want it, but whenever I go to my questions, I can see my questions in the *recently deleted questions*.

Comment: If it was deleted 1 year ago, you do _not_ see it in the "recently deleted questions" list. _"What does Stack Overflow do if it's been 1 year since my question was deleted?"_ Nothing. I'm not sure I understand the question here. Can you please [edit] and try to clarify more?

Comment: Still not clear. Are you trying to find your deleted questions that don't appear in the "recently deleted questions" list? If so, unfortunately, that's not possible until you reach 10K reputation. You _could_ flag one of your posts for a moderator intervention and ask them to find your old deleted posts for you. You probably should have a good reason though, otherwise, they might not appreciate it (I'm just speculating).

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192878)? I'm not sure.

Comment: FWIW, I think that disallowing low-rep users from viewing their old deleted questions is a bad decision. I do have a feature request about this though: [Allow all users to use the deleted:1 operator to find their own deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360939/348196). Let's hope it gets picked up soon enough.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari No, questions (and answers) are never _completely_ deleted (except in very rare situations). They're just hidden from the view. The author and 10K users can always see them (if they have a link). No one can find them without a direct link though (except moderator and the post author if they have 10K+ rep).

Comment: It does nothing about them. You can't see them after 6 months, but users with 10k+ reputation and moderators can *always* see deleted posts.

Comment: “Sorry, for taking your attention for this stupid question and my english is too bad so apology for that too.” - You could always use the appropriate tools to fix the grammatical errors.  You shouldn’t feel a need to apologize for your English, since you can do something about it, by using the appropriate tools.